# TouchableOpacity onPress not working in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, stack-navigator, touchableopacity

How do I navigate to a different screen(`CourseDetail.js`) when I clicked on TouchableOpacity. I am using `StackNavigator` for that.But getting error `undefined is not an object evaluating this.props.navigation`. I am pasting my code below.Please do help. I know there is a simple mistake but can't figure out.

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import CourseDetail from './CourseDetail';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
const HomeScreen = ({course, navigation}) =>{
        const {name,featured_image,id} = course;
        const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('CourseDetail', {id})}>
                <Card>
                    <CardSection>
                        <View style={styles.thumbnailContainerStyle}>
                             {course.term_id == '28' ? (<View></View>) : (
                             <Text style={styles.userStyle}>{name}
                             </Text> )}
                        </View>
                    </CardSection>
                </Card>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    };
const ScheduledApp = StackNavigator({
    Home:{
        screen: HomeScreen
    },
    CourseDetail:{
        screen: CourseDetail
    }
});
export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: Try use - export default ScheduledApp

Comment: I'm importing `HomeScreen` in my main page..So can i use `export default ScheduledApp`??

Comment: Yes.. It will refer to your route name that you defined in that function. Please check here - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/quick-start

Comment: My problem is i have a `TabNavigator` when i click on the sidebar i want to navigate to `HomeScreen` and by clicking on the card , want to go to `CourseDetail` page.So how to use a stack navigator inside a tab navigator?

Answer (score 0):

HomeScreen is a functional component , thus it doesn't not have "this" keyword bound to it

Answer (score 0):

You use

> Stateless functional component

Props is available in parameter

```
import CourseDetail from './CourseDetail';
    import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
    const HomeScreen = ({course, navigation}) =>{
            const {name,featured_image,id} = course;
            const {navigate} = navigation; //No need of this.props
            return(
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('CourseDetail', {id})}>
                    <Card>
                        <CardSection>
                            <View style={styles.thumbnailContainerStyle}>
                                 {course.term_id == '28' ? (<View></View>) : (
                                 <Text style={styles.userStyle}>{name}
                                 </Text> )}
                            </View>
                        </CardSection>
                    </Card>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        };
    const ScheduledApp = StackNavigator({
        Home:{
            screen: HomeScreen
        },
        CourseDetail:{
            screen: CourseDetail
        }
    });
    export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: Tried this but getting error when clicked on card `cannot read property navigate of undefined`..what to do?

Comment: Can you share `App.js` code? I think you need to export `ScheduledApp` and add to `App.js`

Comment: [![code for homescreen][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS4yh.png   .Do in need to create a new page for `ScheduledApp` and import it in `App.js`?

Comment: Can i do like this  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUhYb.png. Beacuse `MyHome` is for returning `TabNavigator` and `MyScreen` is for returning `StackNavigator`.

Answer (score 0):

I used withNavigation and resolved my problem:

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
...
const MyHome = () => {
return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {props.navigation.navigate('SecondPage')}}
       <Text>go to other<Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

};
export default withNavigation(MyHome)
```